# PostgreSQL join first result from another table

Tags: postgresql, join, greatest-n-per-group

I have the following tables:

**Posts:**

```
| id (pk) | title   |
|---------|---------|
| 1       | title 1 |
| 2       | title 2 |
```

**Images:**

```
| id (pk) | post_id (fk) | display_order | image_path |
|---------|--------------|---------------|------------|
| 1       | 1            | 1             | image1.jpg |
| 2       | 1            | 2             | image2.jpg |
| 3       | 1            | 0             | image3.jpg |
| 4       | 2            | 1             | image4.jpg |
| 5       | 2            | 1             | image5.jpg |
| 6       | 2            | 2             | image6.jpg |
```

I'd like to retrieve a list of posts each containing the first item in images based on `display_order`.

The desired result would be like this:

```
| id | title   | thumb_path |
|----|---------|------------|
| 1  | title 1 | image3.jpg |
| 2  | title 2 | image4.jpg |
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get only one row on a related table using a lateral join. For example:

```
select p.*, x.image_path
from posts p
left join lateral (
  select *
  from images i where i.post_id = p.id
  order by display_order
  limit 1
) x on true
```

Answer (score 2):

A *classic* PostgreSQL solution is a [`distinct on`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT)  clause.

```
select distinct on (post_id) post_id, image_path
from images 
order by post_id, display_order, image_path
```

The *first* row for each `post_id`  is defined with the `order by`

The rest is a simple `join`

```
with img as (
select distinct on (post_id) post_id, image_path
from images 
order by post_id, display_order, image_path
)
select p.id, p.title, img.image_path
from posts p
join img on p.id = img.post_id
```

Comment: This is also a great answer +1. I'm curious how the execution plans would compare between our solutions.